# how to show appointment of a specific date in a datagridview.??(C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a question:
I am making a calendar application with a database connection (acces database).
With this application people can add appointments and can view their appointments if they press on a date (for example 24 march).
but now all the information of the databse is showed and that is not what i want.
I want to show the  appointments of the button (the date) the user clicked on and not all the oppaintments of the database.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectie = " SELECT * FROM Appointment Order by AppointmentDate ";
            OleDbConnection calendarconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\derek\Dropbox\C#_Project_Calender\Versie 1.0\Kalenderdb.accdb");
            if (calendarconn != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("calendarconn is not null: " + calendarconn);
                calendarconn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selectie, calendarconn);
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Load(reader);

                // achter je grid 
                this.dataGridView1.DataSourc
```

Answer (score 0):

Rephrase your select statement to also filter:

`"SELECT * FROM Appointment WHERE AppointmentDate = @AppointmentDate"`

Then add a parameter to your OleDbCommand object:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppointmentDate", DateTime.Today);`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use "ValueChanged" Event of Datetime Picker.
When a user selects a date from Calendar. Then this event will be fired.

You write the code here and update the query as below:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectie = " SELECT * FROM Appointment where AppointmentDate like '"+dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()+"'  Order by AppointmentDate ";
}
```

You can also change the format of the Date as below.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

27th March 2013 will be displayed as 20130327